# How to set some java arguments for jenkins's job?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Im not quite understand, how does jenkins works. I know it written at java. I know I can launch a java code, by exectuting job. But which java will be used for this job?
For example, I ran jenkins with next command:

> java -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -jar jenkins.war
> --httpPort=8080

Here is 2 java arguments :

> -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps

But this arguments using only for jenkins process, and not be passed to any job from it, right?
If last sentecnce is correct, is there any way to pass java arguments, so job can use it and print it's own  logs?

Comment: Jenkins jobs don't run on Java, they run in Groovy. If you click any build there should be a console page where you can see its logs. For timestamps you can install a plugin. There might even be a plugin for the GC info.

Comment: Also this might interest you: https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2016/11/21/gc-tuning/

Comment: My maven project written on java fetching from git and then running by 'mvn ...' command in job settings. How its possible that java code running in groovy?

Comment: @smelm thanks for link, I already tried smth like that. But it seems like jenkins logs, not code from job. Because my job running 30m+ , but log file has only few rows for this time. While in job's logs I have java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space